# How to give a Seperate colour to single word in two word header

Tags: angular

I Had used to give a optional header in my table code..
Ex:
INCOME/EXPENSE
 Income - green color
Expense - red color..
How to give a seperate colour to both text..?

INCOME/EXPENSE(Rs)

Answer (score 1):

```
<span class="green">INCOME</span>/<span class="red">EXPENSE</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```css
.green{
  color: green;
}

.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="green">INCOME</span> / <span class="red">EXPENSE(Rs)</span>
```